# Magento 2.3 : state 400, no error neither in console neither in log but not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment, place-order

I have quit "original" problem with Magento (if only if was original with Magento :p).
I browse product (for now everything fine), I put product in basket (everything fine), go to checkout and complete form (still fine) and go to payment and when I click on place-order nothing happen.
Going on console - no problem
Going in network - 400 payment-information (yes 400 neither 500 neither 404 :p)
then checking var/log - no problem (ಠ_ಠ)
(Of course for dear Magento I do after each change when I want to test :
 - sudo rm -rf generated/*
 - sudo rm -rf var/*
 - sudo rm -rf cache/*
 - sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 - sudo php bin/Magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
 - sudo php bin/magento detup:di:compile
 - sudo chmod -R 777 ./)
Someone had similar issue ? if yes then how to know where come from the issue ?
PS: in case of minus please let me a comment so that I can improve the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to find an error. So for that, you need to enable developer mode and add below code in the root index.php file

To enable developer mode:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Add error log report enable code in the index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Still, you cannot able to see the error, please check in var/logs or try to disable third party payment gateway and see is it working fine if not then please let me know.

And if you can able to see the error then try to fix it from your end or if you need my help please let me know the error, I will try to provide a solution.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't have error log report enable code in the index.php :/ I have just a try catch and a bootstrap run but I have the error which display with php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer even on the home page where I thought it was no error, thank you

Comment: Most welcome @SylvainMichel

Comment: sorry fibnally the problem is not solve, I forgot to do di:compile that why I had message error, but now I am back to the same situation :(

Comment: Could you please provide any error log here?

Comment: if only it was error log, the only logs I have in system.log are :  
Main.ERROR: The specified path is not allowed. [][] (x5) and the debug information main.INFO: Broken reference.
In console I alo have Google Maps JavaScript API error : ApiNotActivatedMapError

Comment: which payment method are you using third party payment getway, if yes then try with default once check money order payment see you are getting the same error or not. Please let me know.

Comment: do you know how I can check which one is used ?

Comment: @SylvainMichel let's discuss in one to one chat that will be easy for you to get an answer quickly?

Comment: thank you a lot for your proposition, however I find a way with the console by looking direclty in the web browser for have error :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to chmod -R 777 'pub', 'generated' and 'var' folders